# Can mouse middle button/scroll wheel button action like trackpad three fingers tap to look up dictionary easier?

Tags: mouse, trackpad, dictionary, look-up

It would be faster query dictionary with middle mouse button click instead of right click then select "Look Up" menu.
Is it possible?

Comment: [Similar question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/237738/126929). If you go to OS `System Preferences > Shortcuts > Services > Searching > Look up dictionary` and add a shortcut, like `Cmd + Alt + F`, for instance. Then it's a matter of how you want to trigger that shortcut. The answers in that link should give you a few ideas for that.  The OP of that question had some ancient mouse with few buttons... so just  so know, if you have a more modern mouse, you may be able to use its software to set a specific button to trigger the shortcut you defined for the `Look up in dictionary` service.

Comment: The behavior is different but acceptable. It opens dictionary instead of a popup. What's better? The answers in the link reminded me and I found my factory mouse application do have a button setting of Look Up behaviors exactly the same like three fingers tap. Thanks.

Comment: You know what. On my second glance at this, I found out that the shortcut for the feature you were talking about is `Cmd + Ctrl + D`, which is different from the service I was talking about. So that would be the one you could've used, had your mouse not had this built in.

Comment: Nice! I can uninstall mouse application now:)

Comment: I don't use any of the dictionary features, so this is all kinda new to me. I just felt I needed to mention, because I just realized that the way this `cmd + ctrl + d` shortcut works is kinda different from what I originally thought. I thought you would have to select a word and then press the shortcut keys, **but actually you only have to hover over a word and press the shortcut keys**.

Comment: Cool. The three fingers gesture just behave like this - auto word detecting. I just forgot this and select first while using the shortcut :) Thanks for mention.

Comment: @Joonas You just accidentally answered a question I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely do it using bettertouchtool, which allows you to reprogram every imput button.